# Looping through XPATH SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I want to download the files of all teams for season 2015-2016 to 2018-2019. However, I am trying to loop through Xpaths that are identical except one number in a bracket to select the different teams and years; the last bracket where I replaced the number with %b and %i.
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import date, timedelta
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException 

chromedriver =("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://evolving-hockey.com/")

#Click Games and then game logs
Gamestab= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/ul/li[6]/a")
Gamestab.click()
Gameslog= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/nav/div/ul/li[6]/ul/li[3]/a")
Gameslog.click()


# Click Teams tab 
Teamstab= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3278-3']/div/ul/li[3]/a")
Teamstab.click()


# Loop all teams and all seasons
## TEAM

for b in range(1,33):

    Team= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3959-3']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div")
    Team.click()
    Teamname= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3959-3']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[%b]" %(b))
    Teamname.click()


# ## Season- 20152016to20182019


    for i in range(1,5):
        Season=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3959-3']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/button")
        Season.click()
        Season1819=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3959-3']/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/ul/li[%s]" %(i))
        Season1819.click()
```

I think it should work by using % and assigning a variable that is, in fact, the iterative element in the for loop, just like I tried, but it does not work.

Comment: I would recommend get all the teamNames using find_elements_by_xpath rather find_elemnt_by_xpath and then click on each of them. Let me know if you need a sample code.

Comment: I would like a solution, please. I edited my code so you can access the website and inspect it. I feel it should work with the logic I am using...I did something similar in the past, but the changing element was a string instead of an integer. I am wondering if I should proceed in another way, because of that.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting ?

Comment: "/div[%b]" %(b))" should this be "/div[%d]" %(b))"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your existing code then please correct the below line. Just changed the **[%b]** to **[%d]** at the end of the xpath string.

Old code:

```
Teamname= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3959-3']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[%b]" %(b))
```

Updated Code:

```
Teamname= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='tab-3959-3']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[%d]" %(b))
```

Here is the refracted code. I haven't got a chance to test this.

```
    #click on Games
    driver.find_element_by_css("ul.nav.navbar-nav a[data-value='Games']").click()
    #click on Game Logs
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.dropdown-menu a[data-value='Game Logs']").click()
    #switch to Teams tab
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul.nav.nav-tabs a[data-value='Teams']").click()
    #click the teams listbox
    teamNames = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-pane active' and @data-value='Teams']//label[.='Team:']//parent::div//div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']").click()
    #get the list of team names
    teams = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-pane active' and @data-value='Teams']//label[.='Team:']//parent::div//div[@class='selectize-dropdown-content']//div[@class='option']")

    # get the list of seasons
    seasons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='tab-pane active' and @data-value='Teams']//select[@id='game_logs_teams_season']/option")
    # iterate through each team
    for team in teams:
        team.click()
        # iterate through each season
        for season in seasons:
            seanson.click()
```

Comment: what is the error? and did you tried replacing "/div[%b]" %(b))" with "/div[%d]" %(b)) in your old logic?

Comment: It is working with : "/div[%b]" %(b))" with "/div[%d]" %(b)).

Comment: I have another question. There is a part that seems to change everyday; [@id='tab-3959-3'] is in every find_by_xpath, but the number changed from yesterday ? What could I do ?

Comment: Ideally you don't need that "id" to identify the elements. Check the css and xpaths that I used in my sample code provided. I vetted all those css and xpaths in the UAT page that you provided.