# Iterate over an xpath (table row) python

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, xpath, html-table, webdriver

I have xpaths as follow:

```
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a
```

As you can see, the tr[] values are changing. I want iterate over these values.

Below is the code I have used

```
search_input = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a')
```

Please let me know How can I iterate over them.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact solution you are looking for but this is the idea.

```
tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr")
for e in tableRows:
    e.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[3]/a")
```

Comment: How can this iterate over tr values ?

Comment: Did you try the solution?

Comment: `td` is a direct descendent of `tr`, so you'd want `./td` instead of `.//td`

Answer (score 0):

if you want all third td for every row, use this:

```
search_input = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[3]/a')
```

If you want only the first 3 rows use this:

```
search_input = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[position() &lt; 4]/td[3]/a')
```

For looping through tds look I.e. this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55059052/3710053)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, assuming 4 elements:

```
for elem in range(1,5):
    element = f"/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[{elem}]/td[3]/a"
    #e = driver.find_element_by_xpath(element)
    #e.click()
    print(element)
```

Prints:

```
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/a
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/a
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/a
/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/a
```

You could do whatever you wanted with the elements in the loop, I just printed to show the value

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Fixed Column number like **3** needs to be be iterated:

```
rows = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr"))
for row in range(1, (rows + 1)):
    local_xpath = ""/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[3]"
    # do something with element
    # cell_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(local_xpath ).text
```

Option 2: Both Row and Col needs to be iterated:

```
rows = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr"))
columns =  len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr/td"))
for row in range(1, (rows + 1)):
    for column in range(1, (columns + 1)):
        local_xpath = ""/html/body/div[1]/table[3]/tbody/tr[" + str(row) + "]/td[" + str(column) + "]"
        # do something with element
        # cell_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(local_xpath ).text
```